# SOAP in iOS - Extracting multiple strings from XML

Tags: objective-c, ios, web-services, soap, xml-parsing

In an iOS program I am making, I am requesting a list of courses with SOAP. This is the reply format

```
<ListCoursesResponse>
          <statusMessage xmlns="xxx">string</statusMessage>
          <courseID xmlns="xxx">string</courseID>
          <courseTitle xmlns="xxx">string</courseTitle>
        </ListCoursesResponse>
        <ListCoursesResponse>
          <statusMessage xmlns="xxx">string</statusMessage>
          <courseID xmlns="xxx">string</courseID>
          <courseTitle xmlns="xxx">string</courseTitle>
</ListCoursesResponse>
```

I am using something along the lines of extrating each separate course as an element in an array, than stepping through the array for each and extracting what is between the Course ID. However, I can't figure out how to extract more than one, as when I return it, it only shows the first course. If I explained this in a bad way, please do tell me so I can try to explain better.

My question is, what's the best way to approach a large list of courses (200+) returned in an XML reponse ?

Edit: Snippet of the code I am using, which only returns 1 ID.

```
NSString *tag1Open = @"<ListCoursesResponse>";
    NSString *tag1Close = @"</ListCoursesResponse>";
    NSString *courseIDOpen = @"<courseID xmlns=\"http://drm.mediuscorp.com/\">";
    NSString *courseIDClose = @"</courseID>";
    result = @"";
    NSArray *XMLarray1 = [XMLResult componentsSeparatedByString:tag1Open];
    if ([XMLarray1 count] > 1) {

        for (int i = 0; i < [XMLarray1 count]; i++) {
            NSString *courseIDString = [[[XMLarray1 objectAtIndex:1]componentsSeparatedByString:tag1Close]objectAtIndex:0];

            NSArray *courseID = [XMLResult componentsSeparatedByString:courseIDOpen];

            if ([courseID count] > 1) {

                for (int i = 0; i < [courseID count]; i++) {
                    courseIDString = [[[courseID objectAtIndex:1]componentsSeparatedByString:courseIDClose]objectAtIndex:0];

                }

            }
        NSLog(@"Course ID: %@",courseIDString);


        }
        [persArray addObject:result];
        for (int i = 0; i < [persArray count]; i++) {
            NSLog(@"%@",[persArray objectAtIndex:i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than try to parse the SOAP XML response response yourself using NSString methods, you would be much better off using an XML Parser to handle this task.  iOS has a built-in XML Parser called [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that is available to you.  (There are also numerous third-party XML Parser components available, of both SAX and DOM varieties)

Here is [a tutorial that gives an example of using NSXMLParser](http://wiki.cs.unh.edu/wiki/index.php/Parsing_XML_data_with_NSXMLParser).